# How to convert the resultset obtained from Sparql SELECT query to a map

Tags: java, sparql, resultset, jena

I am using jena API and I am running a SELECT query which is like this-

```
SELECT ?stream ?numberOfStudents
where {
       ?stream inst:hasNumber ?numberOfStudents
}
```

This is returning a ResultSet where one column is 'stream' and the other one is 'numberOfStudents'. Now I am trying to convert this to a map using the following code-

```
public static getResultAsMap(ResultSet rs){
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
int column1Pos = rs.findColumn("stream");
int column2Pos = rs.findColumn("numberOfStudents");
while (rs.next()) {
String column1 = rs.getString(column1Pos);
int column2 = rs.getInt(column2Pos);
myMap.put(column1, column2);
}
```

But this is getting an error saying the I cannot use the findColumn method. Is there any way of achieving my goal of getting a map from the resultset. If this looks absolutely wrong can some one suggest me a better approach to achieve the goal of getting a map from the resultset.

Comment: Why not use the basics: `rs.getString("stream")` and `rs.getInt("numberOfStudents")`

Comment: That's a weird error...
Can you print the exact stack-trace?
findColumn documentation says:
    SQLException - if the ResultSet object does not contain a column labeled columnLabel, a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set

@ares: That should make no difference - and it is inefficient.

Comment: I am not getting the error in a stacktrace, when I am trying to use this method findcolumn() eclipse is giving error and saying - the method findColumn(String) is undefined for the type ResultSet.

Comment: Well - it is clearly not undefined according to: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#findColumn%28java.lang.String%29

Eclipse is a crap IDE - I'd recommend switching to Gradle (+ Intellij IDEA).

Comment: is it possible that the error is getting thrown as I am using SPARQL but not SQL and jena API.

Comment: It is a different class 'ResultSet', not a JDBC one.  Use getResultVars() to find the variables in a row and ask for them by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative way to convert a sparql ResultSet to a Map in your case.

1.Include the following imports:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
```

2.Use QuerySolution class for conversion:

```
public Map<String, Integer> getResultAsMap(ResultSet rs) {
    Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (; rs.hasNext();) {
        QuerySolution soln = rs.nextSolution();

        String stream = soln.get("stream").toString();
        String noOfStudentsStr = soln.get("numberOfStudents").toString();
        int noOfStudents = Integer.parseInt(noOfStudentsStr);
        myMap.put(stream, noOfStudents);
    }

    return myMap;
}
```